# SQL Join with aggregated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay, so I have these 3 tables (OrderRouting, TimeTicketDet, WorkCntr):

[image]

The 4th table on the right, is what I need my output to look like.

I only need columns from the first 2 tables, but since the WorkCntr columns in those 2 tables don't match, I have to bring in the WorkCntr table to tie them up.  It is a multiple condition join where the JobNo and WorkCntr need to match for every corresponding row.  I need every record from the OrderRouting table to be returned and the TotEstHrs and ManHrs columns need to be summed

So for the first row, we can see JobNo 20166-02 for Cutting, was estimated to be 2.25 hours and total ManHrs is the sum of 1.15, .75 and .25

Here's what I tried so far and it didn't work:

```
SELECT t.JobNo, w.ShortName, SUM(o.TotEstHrs) AS 'Estimated Hours', 
SUM(t.ManHrs) AS 'Man Hours'
FROM TimeTicketDet t LEFT JOIN WorkCntr w ON t.WorkCntr = w.WorkCntr RIGHT 
JOIN OrderRouting o ON t.JobNo = o.JobNo and w.ShortName = o.WorkCntr
WHERE t.JobNo LIKE '20040%'
AND w.ShortName IN ('Cutting', 'Framing', 'Assembly', 'Grinding', 
'Painting', 'Glazing', 'Locknprep', 'Packaging')
GROUP BY t.JobNo, w.ShortName
ORDER BY t.JobNo, w.ShortName;
```

It returns the correct JobNo, ShortName, ManHrs amount, but there are rows from OrderRouting missing and the TotEstHrs value is wrong

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Why `TotalEstHrs` values in the result table are different from those in the OrderRouting table? (i.e. for Framing and Grading)

Comment: Oops, that was just a typo, made those tables up in a hurry.  I've corrected it to not confuse future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the query as below using grouping on a row from `OrderRouting` assuming it's values are unique within a table and used `COALESCE` to return zero man hours where the job has no hours spent on it. Below is the query

```
SELECT
  o.JobNo,
  o.WorkCntr,
  o.TotEstHrs,
  COALESCE(SUM(t.ManHrs), 0) AS ManHrs
FROM OrderRouting o
JOIN WorkCntr w ON 
  o.WorkCntr = w.ShortName
LEFT JOIN TimeTicketDet t ON 
  o.JobNo = t.JobNo
  AND w.WorkCntr = t.WorkCntr
WHERE 
  o.JobNo LIKE '20040%'
  AND w.ShortName IN ('Cutting', 'Framing', 'Assembly', 'Grinding', 'Painting', 'Glazing', 'Locknprep', 'Packaging')
GROUP BY o.JobNo, o.WorkCntr, o.TotEstHrs
ORDER BY o.JobNo, o.WorkCntr;
```

I wonder why you have `o.JobNo LIKE '20040%'` when your sample data doesn't have such jobs, but I guess this is just a mistake so I'm leaving the code intact.

Comment: Thank you so much, the code works like a charm.  I will be studying it closely.  The '20040%' is just the job I happened to be working on at the time, didn't notice I had a diff job number in my sample tables